# What does "rooting" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "rooting" mean in the following passage?

> .... If the sites we visit grow and shrink in popularity in a matter of years, we can't experience the same type of "rooting" we traditionally enjoyed in offline communities. Also, as online friends quickly come and go, what does that say about our ability to form lasting relationships?

The double quotation marks are there in the original text, but it is not mentioned about it.

Comment: Where does the quoted passage come from?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/root has some relevant definitions under **root verb (1)**

Comment: @StuartF I think it is rather _verb **(3)**_.

Comment: Lacking more context, it's impossible to say what it means.  It could mean, in a figurative sense, growing roots.  It could mean digging around (in stacks of books, stashes of antiques, etc).  My money would be on "growing roots".

Comment: Is the source message by any chance from Yahoo Japan?

Comment: @HotLicks  It could be. In a figurative sense I thought having "close relationship with an environment" but your interpretation is helpful.

Comment: @djs I don't think so. It is a short essay written for English learners. I read the whole text but I couldn't find any hint at the exact meaning of "rooting."

Comment: "growing roots"- settling down there in the net as networking, expanding relationships, and establishing online identity ... - is quite satisfactory. Thank you all for your great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom is “to put down roots.” It’s a metaphor from plant growth.

If you put down roots, you know local people well.

Calling it “rooting” is odd.

Comment: Thank you for you helpful answer. I prefer it is an intransitive verb: to grow roots AND also to have a base.

Answer (score 0):

***Rooting*** comes from ***root for***

> to express or show support for (a person, a team, etc.) : to hope for the success of (someone or something)
>
> - Good luck on your upcoming show. Remember that we're all ***rooting*** for you. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/root%20for))

In your passage the *-ing* form is used as a noun.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Thank you for your helpful comments. I understand the context is not enough. I thought having "close relationship with an environment" (merriam-webster noun 3-e ) sounds figurative and is best fitting, but it is a verb. It means like encouraging /giving support each other. Am I right?

Comment: This answer is plausible but we need more context, there are three meanings of *rooting* that could apply